# How to keep a component in the background window stay in focus?

Tags: java, swing, focus

In my program, I have this MAIN window and a HELP window. The HELP window (when opened) is to always stay on top whether it's in focus or not. The issue however is, when I try to `requestFocusInWindow()` for a component in the MAIN window through an action listener that gets fired from the HELP window, it just won't let me do it.

What is the proper way of accomplishing this?
TY :)

Edit:

As requested, here's a short example of what I'm trying to accomplish. Essentially I need the button inside the HELP window to trigger focus to the TextField inside the Main window.

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;

    import javax.swing.*;

    public class Main {

        public static void initGUI() {
            mainFrame = new JFrame("Main");
            helpFrame = new JFrame("Help");

            mainFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 200));
            helpFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 200));

            mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            helpFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            mainFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            helpFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

            mainTextView = new JTextField("", 20);

            mainButton = new JButton("Open Help");
            helpButton = new JButton("Request Focus");

            mainButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (e.getSource().equals(mainButton)) {
                        helpFrame.pack();
                        helpFrame.setVisible(true);
                    }
                }
            });

            helpButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (e.getSource().equals(helpButton))
                        System.out.println("Focus requested:" + mainTextView.requestFocusInWindow());
                }
            });

            helpFrame.add(helpButton);

            mainFrame.add(mainTextView);
            mainFrame.add(mainButton);

            mainFrame.pack();
            mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            initGUI();
        }

        static JFrame mainFrame, helpFrame;

        static JTextField mainTextView;

        static JButton mainButton, helpButton;
    }
```

Comment: Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. In your SSCCE the MAIN frame would have a button to display the HELP frame and the Help frame would have a button to request focus back on the main frame button. Get that working first.

Answer (score 0):

So turns out the fix was rather trivial. If `requestFocus()` is used instead of `requestFocusInWindow()`, it seems to work just fine.

Kinda feel stupid for how much time I spent on this :P

```
helpButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource().equals(helpButton))
            mainTextView.requestFocus();
    }
});
```